# Assign a name to thread on request arrival

Tags: spring, spring-security, annotations, request, jax-ws

I have a JEE7 webapp that uses jax-ws annotations to define some services, and uses spring framework.

I want to assign a name of choice to the thread that serves a request when it arrives.

I thought about putting Thread.currentThread().setName("") and this works fine if I put this row inside every @path annotated method, but it's a bit pointless to add the same code in every method. I am thinking to put it in a earlier stage.

Is there some sort of "@onrequest" annotation to define some code common to all request?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working with a filter. I just declared a new filter in web.xml and then I implemented the filter class.

In web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>threadRenamingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>RestRequestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>threadRenamingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In filter class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class RestRequestFilter implements Filter {

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1, FilterChain arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //Before request execution
        Date now = new Date();
        Long startTime = now.getTime();
        String newName = startTime.toString();
        log.trace("Thread " + newName + " started at: " + now.toString());
        //renaming of the thread with the time of spawn
        Thread.currentThread().setName(newName);
        //Request execution
        arg2.doFilter(arg0, arg1);
        //After request execution
        now = new Date();
        Long endTime = now.getTime();
        Long executionTime = endTime - startTime;
        log.trace("Thread " + newName + " end at: " + now.toString());
        log.debug("Thread " + newName + " completed in: " + executionTime + "ms");
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use interceptors to handle that, basically you need to write a class which implements:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html

and wire it with spring. Then in method postHandle or preHandle you do what you want ; )

Here is some tutorial how to do that:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-interceptor-example/

you can also take a look at filters.

Comment: I was just thinking about that. I will definitely try and let you know. Thanks very much.

Comment: I tried to add that interceptor to the cxf servlet, but it doesn't work. I need something for cxf.

Comment: then maybe filter which will run before your code can be helpful?

Comment: It seems that interceptors can be binded to managed classes, but the rest class is not a managed class. Do you have any examples of interceptors applied to REST (cxf or jersey is not important) classes? I want the interceptor to intercept the call BEFORE the cxf/jersey and security layers are called. I need this to log the whole performance of the rest request and to change the thread name for tracking purposes.

Comment: I dont. But im using interceptors for spring mvc controllers. If you are using spring and spring security then interceptors will run too late for you - after spring security logic. In this case you probably need to implement filter, which will be injected before spring listeners. Do you have any web.xml in your project? If so, then it should be easy to set up.

Comment: Yes, I have the web.xml that just defines some filters for cxf. I will try to add another two filter one for request and one for response in a way to allow thread renaming and to use thread local to monitor performance. I'll keep in touch with solution as soon as I get it working.

Comment: I got this working with a filter. I just declared a new filter in web.xml and then I implemented the filter class.